# Can't get a value from LMDB

Tags: c++, c, lmdb

I'm trying to store and fetch some data from LMDB. Data seems to be stored, I can see the keys in my database, but it gives me `MDB_NOTFOUND` when I try to fetch the value with the same ID I have just stored it under.

**Database opening**

```
    MDB_env* environment;
    MDB_dbi main;
    MDB_dbi order;
    mdb_env_create(&environment);
    mdb_env_set_maxdbs(environment, 2);
    mdb_env_open(environment, path.toStdString().c_str(), 0, 0664);

    int rc;
    MDB_txn *txn;
    mdb_txn_begin(environment, NULL, 0, &txn);
    mdb_dbi_open(txn, "main", MDB_CREATE, &main);
    mdb_dbi_open(txn, "order", MDB_CREATE | MDB_INTEGERKEY, &order);
    mdb_txn_commit(txn);
```

**Insertion**

```
void Core::Archive::addElement(const Shared::Message& message) {
    QByteArray ba;
    QDataStream ds(&ba, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    message.serialize(ds);
    uint64_t stamp = message.getTime().toMSecsSinceEpoch();
    const std::string& id = message.getId().toStdString();

    MDB_val lmdbKey, lmdbData;
    lmdbKey.mv_size = id.size();
    lmdbKey.mv_data = (uint8_t*)id.c_str();
    lmdbData.mv_size = ba.size();
    lmdbData.mv_data = (uint8_t*)ba.data();
    MDB_txn *txn;
    mdb_txn_begin(environment, NULL, 0, &txn);
    int rc;
    rc = mdb_put(txn, main, &lmdbKey, &lmdbData, 0);
    if (rc == 0) {
        MDB_val orderKey;
        orderKey.mv_size = 8;
        orderKey.mv_data = (uint8_t*) &stamp;

        rc = mdb_put(txn, order, &orderKey, &lmdbKey, 0);
        if (rc) {
            mdb_txn_abort(txn);
        } else {
            rc = mdb_txn_commit(txn);
            if (rc) {
                qDebug() << "A transaction error: " << mdb_strerror(rc);
            }
        }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "An element couldn't been added to the archive, skipping" << mdb_strerror(rc);
        mdb_txn_abort(txn);
    }
}
```

**Fetching**

```
Shared::Message Core::Archive::getElement(const QString& id) {
    MDB_val lmdbKey, lmdbData;
    lmdbKey.mv_size = id.toStdString().size();
    lmdbKey.mv_data = (uint8_t*)id.toStdString().c_str();

    MDB_txn *txn;
    int rc;
    mdb_txn_begin(environment, NULL, MDB_RDONLY, &txn);
    rc = mdb_get(txn, main, &lmdbKey, &lmdbData);
    if (rc) {
        qDebug() <<"Get error: " << mdb_strerror(rc);
        mdb_txn_abort(txn);
        throw NotFound(id.toStdString(), jid.toStdString());
    } else {
        //it never comes here
    }
}
```

**Testing code**

```
Core::Archive ar();
ar.open("Test");
Shared::Message msg1;
msg1.generateRandomId();
msg1.setBody("oldest");
msg1.setTime(QDateTime::currentDateTime().addDays(-7));
Shared::Message msg2;
msg2.generateRandomId();
msg2.setBody("Middle");
msg2.setTime(QDateTime::currentDateTime().addDays(-4));
Shared::Message msg3;
msg3.generateRandomId();
msg3.setBody("newest");
msg3.setTime(QDateTime::currentDateTime());

ar.addElement(msg2);
ar.addElement(msg3);
ar.addElement(msg1);

Shared::Message d0 = ar.getElement(msg1.getId());
```

My logs show stored keys. I can see the required key, I can even compare it with the requested key if I use cursors to scroll over the whole storage, it even shows they are equal, but `mdb_cursor_get` or `mdb_get` constantly give me `MDB_NOTFOUND`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. No matter what I put into database, I have to read it as a char*

Had to modify fetching code

```
lmdbKey.mv_data = (uint8_t*)id.toStdString().c_str();
```

I had to change it to

```
lmdbKey.mv_data = (char*)id.toStdString().c_str();
```

and it worked